# "I see a great city whose glory will touch the stars" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

What is the best translation of the following English sentence into Latin?

> ***I see a great city whose glory will touch the stars.***

It was said by a [legendary mythological figure called Libuše [Libushe] while having a vision about the future of the city Prague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libu%C5%A1e). My attempt:

*Ego urbem maximam momentam video ille gloria stellas tanget.*

EDIT 1.0: Here is my way of doing the translation:

> *Ego*=I
>
> *urbem*=accusative of *urbs*
>
> *maximam momentam* = feminine accusative of "of great importance"
>
> *video*=I see

(word order=SOV)

> *ille*=which, that
>
> *gloria*=glory
>
> *stellas*=accusative plural of *stella*, a star
>
> *tanget*=3rd person singular future of *tangere*, to touch

Answer (score 9):

It is perhaps not necessary for us to translate the English to Latin, because the 12th century Chronica Boemorum, which recounts the story of this prophecy, was written in Latin. The sentence ([Book 1, Chapter IX](https://daten.digitale-sammlungen.de/bsb00000683/images/index.html?id=00000683&seite=116)) is:

> Urbem conspicio, fama quae sidera tanget

Your translation is rather more literal and generally correct as well, though a relative pronoun (e.g. cuius, meaning "whose") would required instead of a demonstrative (ille).

Answer (score 6):

Faustus has the actual Latin phrase, but I do want to make just two small comments about your translation:

You don't actually need to say *ego*, as it is implied in *video*. Adding it typically emphasizes the subject, so that it sounds more like "It is *I* who see..."

For "great city," you can simply do *urbem magnam*, but if you want to say "of great importance," that phrase would go into the genitive or ablative, not the accusative.